# El each me recorre siempre todos los checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

lo que sucede es que necesito que cada que ejecute el click, me capture el valor del padre que acabo de seleccionar, pero cada que ejecuto el click, me captura todos los valores de los input seleccionados y no solo al que le acabo de dar click, no logro que funcione como quiero

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  <div class="padre">
    <div class="hijo">
      <label >
        <input type="checkbox">
        Test 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <label >
        <input type="checkbox">
        Test 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <label >
        <input type="checkbox">
        Test 3
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <label >
        <input type="checkbox">
        Test 4
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <label >
        <input type="checkbox">
        Test 5
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="active">
    
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').click(function() {
      $('input:checked').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
          console.log ($(this).parent('label').text());
       }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dándole una leída rápida, puedes asignarles ID's a cada item porque todos comparten el mismo type.

Comment: tu problema es que recorres, como tu lo dices, todos los elementos cuando haces click. Tendrías que detectar el evento change y no click en el check box y solo chequear el estado de ese ítem y no de todos. El each ese no creo que sea útil. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Si solo quieres seleccionar el texto del label padre actual, entonces no debes de implementar el `each` porque este recorrera todo input que esten `checked`. Tambien cambie el evento `click` por `change` que es lo que comunmente se utiliza para campos `checkbox`. Si necesitas el click solo reemplaza el nombre del evento.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log ($(this).parent('label').text());
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">
    <label >
      <input type="checkbox">
      Test 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <label >
      <input type="checkbox">
      Test 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <label >
      <input type="checkbox">
      Test 3
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <label >
      <input type="checkbox">
      Test 4
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <label >
      <input type="checkbox">
      Test 5
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="active">
</div>
```

Te dejo unos enlaces de documentacion para que los revises.

> [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/): El evento change se envía a un elemento cuando cambia su valor. Este evento está limitado a elementos `<input>`, cuadros de texto `<textarea>` y elementos de seleccion `<select>`. Para las casillas de selección, casillas de verificación y botones de radio, el evento se activa inmediatamente cuando el usuario hace una selección con el mouse, pero para los otros tipos de elementos, el evento se aplaza hasta que el elemento pierde el foco.
>
> [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/): función de iterador genérico, que se puede utilizar para iterar sin problemas sobre objetos y matrices.